# Is there a way to add a user to a group chat with discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am working with `discord.py` and I am trying to make self commands.

I need

- the function/command/method to add a user to a group chat (if you have them added), and
- The function/command/method to leave a group chat you're in.

A method to get the group chat ID will also come in handy.

I was reading [the docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=group#discord.ChannelType.group) and found this but it didn't fully suit my purposes.

I'd also really appreciate a way to change the group chat name and icon.

Comment: Why did you tag `discord.js` if you're using `discord.py`

Comment: There's quite a lot to unpack here. First, what have you tried so far? A snippet of your code would make this clear as well as give context to what you mean by "didn't fully suit my purposes".

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [Stack Overflow cannot answer customer support questions](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745). Please consider contacting customer support for the company in question with your issues.

Answer (score 3):

Automating user accounts (A.K.A. Self-Bots) is against discords ToS. For this reason we can't help you with your question.

You can read more about discords opinion regarding self bots [here](https://support.discord.com/hc/en-us/articles/115002192352-Automated-user-accounts-self-bots-).